# How to search tag wikis or tag excerpts

Tags: support, search, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

It looks like the [tag search](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) only searches for matching tag names.

[image]

Is there a way to search tag wikis or even tag excerpts?

Comment: I think this could be a [feature-request] if you imply that you want to searcch within tag excerpts.

Comment: Well... You can always use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), for example, [all tags with example.com in excerpt or wiki](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1334708?Parameter=example.com)

Comment: @BMPL okay, so there is no way on the main site (using URL hacking or something). I agree, it would be a helpful feature. Let's say someone wants to search "tags about that free Stanford course" if you don't know the [tag:cs193p] tag it's hard to find.